# Positioning the dialog box just below a commandLink

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How to specify the position for the primefaces `dialog`. I am able to use the attribute as`position=top`  but can I define the exact position in terms of x,y coordinates.

I actually need to display the dialog box just below a `commandLink` component. Any help on how I can achieve that is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the position attribute will take x,y coordinates.

```
<p:dialog header="My Dialog" widgetVar="dialog" position="50,100"></p:dialog>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark! Though this works fine but I couldnt figure out a way to programmatically find the co-ordinates of `commandLink` component above it or even better anyhow set it to be rendered just below commandLink. If you could perhaps help on this please.

Comment: @Marcos Your Welcome, you may want to ask another question, How to programmatically find component coordinates, I would think the only way to do that is using Javascript.